# Как вывести строку с градиентным затуханием по краям?

Tags: delphi, графика, градиент, vcl

Будет компонент, в нём можно будет мышкой скролить строку (или изображение) влево/вправо, строка длинная, потому хотелось бы сделать какой-то линейный градиент в виде маски по краям, чтобы был эффект появляющегося из ниоткуда текста в начале и исчезающего в конце.
Каким образом это организовать в Delphi?

Comment: Компоненты VCL или FMX?

Comment: Компоненты VCL...

Comment: Создать в памяти PNG с прозрачностью. Шириной с компонент и высотой в 1px. Залить цветом компонента (бэкграунд). Сделать на нем повдоль градиентную прозрачность (например, от 0 до 255 за 20px, 255 на ширину компонента-40px, от 255 до 0 за 20px) и накладывать на текст во всю высоту строки при перерисовке.

Comment: @dr. F.I.N., а почему не взять стандартный Bitmap, не задать 32бита и не пересчитать эти полоски справа и слева попиксельно? Должно же сработать?

Comment: @Isaev, можно и битмап. Роли нет. Моя идея в том, что бы не пересчитывать каждый раз градиент при сдвиге текста, а просто накладывать готовую заливку на текст. Т.е. единожды (например при создании компонента, или вообще в ресурсы засунуть готовую) подготовить градиентно-прозрачную заливку и уже потом накладывать. Можно даже сделать два кусочка, для левой и правой стороны.

Comment: @dr. F.I.N, сделал, получается не убедительно) Тут затухание аж по 80 пикселей с каждой стороны, но смотрится это вовсе не равномерно... https://i.imgur.com/JSHZPGu.png видимо яркость человеческий глаз воспринимает не линейно и нужна какая-то функция.

Comment: Сделайте затухание по Sin(x), например, или по Sqr(x). Вариантов много

Comment: @Kromster, да по sin(x) [0..pi/2] довольно не плохо, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создать в памяти PNG с прозрачностью. Шириной с компонент и высотой в 1px. Залить цветом компонента (бэкграунд). Сделать на нем вдоль градиентную прозрачность (например, от 0 до 255 за 20px, 255 на ширину компонента-40px, от 255 до 0 за 20px) и накладывать на текст во всю высоту строки при перерисовке.

Можно и стандартный битмап. Роли нет. Идея в том, что бы не пересчитывать каждый раз градиент при сдвиге текста, а просто накладывать готовую заливку на текст. Т.е. единожды (например при создании компонента, или вообще в ресурсы засунуть готовую) подготовить градиентно-прозрачную заливку и уже потом накладывать. Можно даже сделать два кусочка, для левой и правой стороны.

Если затухание воспринимается слишком неравномерно, то попробуйте сделать его по Sin(x), например, или по Sqr(x). Вариантов много.

Comment: В общем получилось как-то так: https://i.imgur.com/AI8h69v.png через затухание через Sin(x), я вполне удовлетворён)

Comment: @Isaev кажется что по краям текст одновременно с прозрачностью становится еще и светлее.

Comment: Хм, а как ещё тёмному цвету стать прозрачным на более светлом фоне? Он же должен осветлиться до него, чтобы слиться?!

Comment: @Isaev присмотритесь к самому краю, там текст становится даже светлее фона. Скорее всего, у вас используется не совсем правильная функция смешения цвета.

Comment: Надо проверить под лупой, спасибо... Т.к. при некоторых сочетаниях цветов страннова-то выглядит, может и закрался где-то баг

Comment: светлый шрифт затемняется вроде правильно, а при осветлении тёмного тени действительно местами светлее фона становятся https://i.imgur.com/7MmOiR0.png будем искать)

Comment: @Isaev Если вы покажете как смешиваются цвета (например отдельным вопросом), то возможно ошибка будет найдена.

Comment: да уже обсуждалось, коэффициент гамма коррекции я конечно не учитывал, надо поправить. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521003/gamma-correction-formula-gamma-or-1-gamma